# How to do the xml schema validation in Spring Rest

Tags: spring, rest, xsd-validation, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

I am trying to develope the Spring Rest API. I am using JAXB class and xsd files for validation. I set the schema in springbean.xml. But validation is not happening against xsd.

Comment: You have to show some code so people can help you. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask